# How to do a (near) one way communication from client to server

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, httprequest

I want to send message `m` and data `v` to the server, and do not need to do anything particularly with the response on the client Javascript. Is there a request method for doing this? If not, I want to return a minimally acceptable string to the client (which will not be processed). What is the best way to do this?

I tried doing this on the Javascript,

```
function report(m,v){
  io=new XMLHttpRequest();
  io.open("POST","http://localhost:3000?m="+m,true);
  io.send(JSON.stringify(v));
  return false;
};
```

and as a response to it, I sent what I think is a minimum serialized string created by Ruby like

```
[].to_json
```

And the client Javascript says `the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal State Error)`.

**Edit**

On the server side, I have a Ruby code like this:

```
Rack::Handler::Thin.run(Rack::Builder.new do
  map("/") do
    run(->env{[200, {}, [server.ajax(
      Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env["QUERY_STRING"]),
      env["rack.input"].read
    )]]})
  end
end, Port: 3000)
```

where `server.ajax` method is like this:

```
def ajax h, v
  m, v = h["m"].to_sym, JSON.parse(v)
  case m
  ...
  when :error
    puts m
    p v
    return "" # or `[].to_json` or whatever
  ...
  end
end
```

and in the particular case, I have the message `m` which is `'error'`. And I get output from the code above, so I think the problem is with the response.

Comment: You can just send back an empty string. Ajax doesn't check for string type or syntax.

Comment: @Linuxios Isee. But I get 500 error. I cannot figure out what the cause is.

Comment: The problem seems to be your request, not the response handling. You should be able to simply respond with a 200 from the server, nothing else is required.

Comment: In Rails you can use the `ActionController#head` method to simply return a 200.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly I don't user Rails. And it seems that the request is correctly sent to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 is an internal server error. It is likely that you have some run-time error happen in your handling function on the server. Unfortunately, simply based on the number and the code you posted, it might be very hard to find out what's going on (and I don't know Ruby too well). Try to get an actual stack trace from the server rather than just the generic 500 HTTP status code.

As posted in the comments already, the browser won't care about the body content of your reply, so you can simply leave it empty.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that is was a server side error as you said.